# Alignment of Rotated Progress Bar

Tags: wpf

I'm having some trouble displaying a rotated progress bar.  Ideally I would like to have no gap between the progress bar and textblock. Any suggestions?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">                
            <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="430">
                <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
            </ProgressBar>

            <TextBlock Width="100" Height="500" Text="test" />
 </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try LayoutTransofrm instead of RenderTransform:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="430">
            <ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
            </ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
        </ProgressBar>

        <TextBlock Width="100" Height="500" Text="test" />
    </StackPanel>
```